# Best way to establish a private secure connection between an Azure App Service and a AWS ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-web-app-service, amazon-ecs

I have an app service (Rest API) in Azure and I am planning on hosting another service that has to be integrated with the Azure app service. Could someone please let me know the preferred way(s) to make sure the communication is on a private secure channel?

Comment: As far as simple solution goes, can't you just setup Security Group, block everything and only whitelist the Azure IP address? It literally takes 1 min to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the official Azure Docs, you have three options, I can say that the VPN option will be one of the easiest ones, but you can have problems like limited throughput, unpredictable routing via the public internet, and the cost of the AWS and Azure data transfer fees.

To understand better which option to use you can check this flow chart:

[image]

**Option 1**: Connect Azure ExpressRoute and the other cloud provider's equivalent private connection. The customer manages routing.

[image]

**Option 2**: Connect ExpressRoute and the other cloud provider's equivalent private connection. A cloud exchange provider handles routing.

[image]

**Option 3**: Use Site-to-Site VPN over the internet. For more information, see [Connect on-premises networks to Azure by using Site-to-Site VPN gateways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/connect-on-premises-network-with-vpn-gateway/2-connect-on-premises-networks-to-azure-using-site-to-site-vpn-gateways).

[image]

The options 1 and 2 are the best options to avoid use of the public internet, if you require an SLA, if you want predictable throughput, or need to handle data volume transfer. Consider whether to use a customer-managed routing or a cloud exchange provider if you haven't implemented ExpressRoute already.

In the AWS side, you will be able to configure your VPC, to understand how to do this check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-public-private-vpc.html).

For more information about these three options, check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/connectivity-to-other-providers)

Comment: Hmm... I thought I put 100 points as bounty but you seem to only have 50.

Comment: @AttRigh All the bounty points are received only if the answer is accepted, if not only half are sent to the answer with more votes